# Using lm() with lag() on time series object in R

Tags: r

I have a time series object (ts / mts) called "mydata".
(The dates go from 1980 to 2014)

```
class(mydata) [1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"

colnames(mydata)  [1] "inflation"       "unemployment"  

equation1 = lm(inflation ~ unemployment + lag(unemployment, 1), data = mydata)
```

Two questions: 
 1.  Have I specified the lag() correctly?    I seem to get lots of NA's.
 2.  How do I get the residuals to keep the same dates as the time-series? 
 (i.e:  "1981 to 2014" instead of just "1 to 34")

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example using `dput`

Answer (score 0):

1. you can try print the output of both unemployment and lagged unemployment to see if there is something unusual happening otherwise the function specification looks fine to me.
2. You can use `cbind(mydata,equation1$residuals)` to bind residual together with the rest of your time series so that it will also have the same time.