# Linear regression using time lagged predictors (independent variables) for forecasting purpose

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, forecasting

I'm working on forecasting the Monthly Average Precipitation of a geographical region in India (Assam and Meghalaya subdivision). For this purpose, I'm using the Monthly Average Air Temperature data and Monthly Averaged Relative Humidity data (which I extracted and averaged it spatially from the netCDF4 file for this geographical region present on the NOAA website) as the independent variables(predictors).

For the forecasting purpose, I want to model a linear regression with Precipitation as the dependent variable and "Air Temperature" and "Relative Humidity" data as the independent variables such that they're having a time-lagged effect in the regression.

The Linear regression equation should look like:

[Please follow this link for the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1V0z.jpg)

Here, "Y" is Precipitation, "X" is Air Temperature and "Z" is Relative Humidity.

The sample "Training data" is as follows:

```
   ID       Time Precipitation Air_Temperature Relative_Humidity
1   1 1948-01-01           105        20.31194          81.64137
2   2 1948-02-01           397        21.21052          80.20120
3   3 1948-03-01           594        22.14363          81.94274
4   4 1948-04-01          2653        20.79417          78.89908
5   5 1948-05-01          7058        20.43589          82.99959
6   6 1948-06-01          5328        18.10059          77.91983
7   7 1948-07-01          4882        16.63936          76.25758
8   8 1948-08-01          3979        16.56065          76.89210
9   9 1948-09-01          2625        16.95542          76.80116
10 10 1948-10-01          2578        17.13323          75.62411
```

And a segment of "Test data" is as follows:

```
        ID       Time Precipitation Air_Temperature Relative_Humidity
    1  663 2003-03-01           862        21.27210          79.77419
    2  664 2003-04-01          1812        20.44042          79.42500
    3  665 2003-05-01          1941        19.24267          79.57057
    4  666 2003-06-01          4981        18.53784          80.67292
    5  667 2003-07-01          4263        17.21581          79.97178
    6  668 2003-08-01          2436        16.88686          81.37097
    7  669 2003-09-01          2322        16.23134          77.63333
    8  670 2003-10-01          2220        17.40589          81.14516
    9  671 2003-11-01           131        19.01159          79.15000
    10 672 2003-12-01           241        20.86234          79.05847
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this question helps you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465154/using-lm-with-lag-on-time-series-object-in-r

Comment: Hey, I think it is unclear what you are asking. Are you looking for help on how to generate lagged independent variables? Or do you need help on the forecasting technique itself?

Comment: @tifu Actually, I'm looking for help on both forecasting technique and producing lagged independent variables.

Comment: Consider the [statistics sister site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) where you will many questions and answers related to forecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Reacting to your clarification in the comments, here is one of many ways to produce lagged variables, using the `lag` function within `dplyr` (I am also adding a new row here for later forecasting):

```
df %>%
   add_row(ID = 11, Time = "1948-11-01") %>%
   mutate(Air_Temperature_lagged = dplyr::lag(Air_Temperature, 1),
          Relative_Humidity_lagged = dplyr::lag(Relative_Humidity, 1)) -> df.withlags
```

You can then fit a straightforward linear regression using `lm`, with `Precipitation` as your dependent variable and the lagged versions of the two other variables as the predictor:

```
precip.model <- lm(data = df.withlags, Precipitation ~ Air_Temperature_lagged + Relative_Humidity_lagged)
```

You could then apply your coefficients to your most recent values in `Air_Temperature` and `Relative_Humidity` to forecast the precipitation for November of 1948 using the `predict` function.

```
predict(precip.model, newdata = df.withlags)
  1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11 
  NA 2929.566 3512.551 3236.421 3778.742 2586.012 3473.482 3615.884 3426.378 3534.965 3893.255
```

The model's prediction is `3893.255`.

Note that this model will only allow you to forecast one time period into the future, since you don't have more information in your predictors.

Comment: Thanks @tifu, but the data which I've provided above is just a segment of training data (it has monthly values starting from 1948 to 2003) from which I was planning to train the linear regression model. After training the model, I want the model to predict the future values for them to compare with test data set (which has monthly values from 2003 to 2016).

Comment: So can you please explain me your answer how I can achieve what I've planned for.

Comment: If you don‘t have information on your predictors for the period you are interested in forecasting, you cannot achieve what you have planned for, at least not without forecasting values for the predictors as well

Comment: I have the future values of the predictors as well as the dependent variable already stored in the "test set" dataframe but don't know if they have any role in forecasting of precipitation. Can you help me out how to use them?

Comment: I'll add a segment of data from the test set as well.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. What do you want to forecast, exactly? All of the values in your test dataset without actually using the precipitation data? In that case, you can just apply the estimates of your regression to the lagged versions of your independent variables in the test data. I don't see how that would qualify as forecasting, though, to be honest.